# Opening Geojson file in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I have gone through all codes here explaining how to add geojson file in openlayers.But is there way to add the same from a local drive something like

c:\test\sample.geojson

instead of URL like

www.sdssd.com\sample.geojson

I mean is it mandatory to host a geojson file and then only open it.

please help.

Shyam

Answer (score 0):

Opening from a local drive will not work.

This would be a huge security hole in each browser.
Only workaround is to provide an upload feature so users can upload the geojson file to your server, and after uploaded, displayed from that server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really use Openlayers for using Geojson (prefer Leaflet.js), but it would probably open in your local drive if that's where the HTML file referenced it.  No one else would be able to use it though unless they downloaded it into the same directory structure as you.